# Should I use -ms prefix?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, vendor-prefix

> Windows Internet Explorer 8. The -ms-accelerator attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a synonym for accelerator in IE8 Standards mode.

This text is from the MSDN reference.

I'm not sure, should I use `-ms` vendor in this case or not.

`Can be used as a synonym` - they mean I can ommit a vendor prefix, or it should be used for ie8?

This question isn't specific for `accelerator` only.

Answer (score 2):

`-ms-` is simply Trident's prefix. Like `-webkit-` is for webkit, `-moz-` for gecko, and so on and so forth. It's simply used to trial experimental features.

Comment: It really depends on the rule. [Take a look at this](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/)

Comment: And in this case, yes, it should.